# I am calling a function using java script but its not calling that method below code is not hitting secretraitNames() function

Tags: java, javascript, liferay, liferay-6

```html
<aui:select name="secretaryname" id="secretarynames" label="Secretary Name" onClick="secretraitNames()" ></aui:select>                    
<script type="text/javascript">
    function secretraitNames(){ 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Show the entire element on which you all it. also, there is no code in your function, how do you know it's not being called?

Comment: try `onclick`, that would work

Comment: oh you need `onClientClick` or somethinng like that if you <aui:select is a server tag

Comment: @Nirraj: Don't put the whole question in the post's title. It makes the question very unclear.

Comment: onClick / onclick both should work. You have improper code. Implement as suggested by @Hanzallah Afgan

Answer (score 1):

It is working but you have nothing inside the tag you want to click.
More you haven't any single statement inside the function body.
Debug it as below.

```
<aui:select name="secretaryname" id="secretarynames" label="Secretary Name" onclick="secretraitNames()" >Click here</aui:select>                    
<script type="text/javascript">
    function secretraitNames(){ 
        alert("welcome");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: <aui:select name="managedby"  id="managedby" class="managedby" label="Managed By" showEmptyOption="true" onChange="getCommitteManagers(this.val);" >
   <%
    for(Organization organization : organizationList ){
   %>
     <aui:option  value="<%= organization.getOrganizationId()%>"><%= organization.getName() %></aui:option>
   <%
    }
   %>function getCommitteManagers(obj) {
   </aui:select>    function getCommitteManagers(obj) {
 alert('in......./');}</script>

Comment: No friend its not working for me.. The code is exactly like above

Comment: @NirrajSingh May you post it in formatted code? May be as a fiddle. Please don't post the whole question in comment.

Comment: Solution......AUI().use('aui-base','aui-io-request', function(A){
  A.io.request(addCommiteeURL,{
   dataType: 'json',
   method: 'POST',
   data: { 
     SelectedType:selectedType
   },
   on: {
    success: function(JsonData) {
     $("#committeeForm").html(this.get('responseData'));
    },
    failure:function(){
     alert('Internal Error Occured');
    }
   }
  });
 });